# How to determine the version of PyJWT?

Tags: python, pyjwt

I have two different software environments (**Environment A** and **Environment B**) and I'm trying to run PyJWT on both environments. It is working perfectly fine on one environment **Environment A** but fail on **Environment B**.

The error I'm getting on **Environment B** when I call `jwt.encode()` with `algorithm` == `ES` is: `Algorithm not supported`.

I'm trying to figure out why it works on **Environment A** but not **Environment B**. It seems like the two environments have different versions of PyJWT installed. But determining which version of PyJWT is installed on **Environment B** is proving difficult for me. How can I do it??

I ran the following instrumented code on both **Environment A** and **Environment B**:

```
import jwt, cryptography, sys, pkg_resources

my_private_key = """XXXXX"""
my_public_key = """YYYYYY"""
original = {"Hello": "World"}
print "sys.version = {}".format(str(sys.version))

try:
    print "dir(jwt) = {}".format(str(dir(jwt)))
except Exception as e:
    print "Failed to get dir of jwt module: {}".format(e)

try:
    print "dir(cryptography) = {}".format(str(dir(cryptography)))
except Exception as e:
    print "Failed to get dir of cryptography module: {}".format(e)

try:
    print "jwt = {}".format(str(jwt.__version__))
except Exception as e:
    print "Failed to get version of jwt module using .__version: {}".format(e)
try:
    print "cryptography = {}".format(str(cryptography.__version__))
except Exception as e:
    print "Failed to get version of cryptography module using .__version: {}".format(e)

try:
    print "pkg_resources.require('jwt')[0].version = {}".format(str(pkg_resources.require("jwt")[0].version))
except Exception as e:
    print "Failed to get version of jwt module via pkg_resources: {}".format(e)

try:
    print "pkg_resources.require('cryptography')[0].version = {}".format(str(pkg_resources.require("cryptography")[0].version))
except Exception as e:
    print "Failed to get version of cryptography module via pkg_resources: {}".format(e)

try:
    print "original = {}".format(str(original))
    encoded = jwt.encode(original, my_private_key, algorithm='ES256')
except Exception as e:
    print "encoding exception = {}".format(str(e))
else:
    try:
        print "encoded = {}".format(str(encoded))
        unencoded = jwt.decode(encoded, my_public_key, algorithms=['ES256'])
    except Exception as e:
        print "decoding exception = {}".format(str(e))
    else:
        print "unencoded = {}".format(str(unencoded))
```

On **Environment A**, the encoding succeeds:

```
sys.version = 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016, 22:14:00)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]
dir(jwt) = ['DecodeError', 'ExpiredSignature', 'ExpiredSignatureError', 'ImmatureSignatureError', 'InvalidAudience', 'InvalidAudienceError', 'InvalidIssuedAtError', 'InvalidIssuer', 'InvalidIssuerError', 'InvalidTokenError', 'MissingRequiredClaimError', 'PyJWS', 'PyJWT', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', '__version__', 'algorithms', 'api_jws', 'api_jwt', 'compat', 'decode', 'encode', 'exceptions', 'get_unverified_header', 'register_algorithm', 'unregister_algorithm', 'utils']
dir(cryptography) = ['__about__', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__summary__', '__title__', '__uri__', '__version__', 'absolute_import', 'division', 'exceptions', 'hazmat', 'print_function', 'sys', 'utils', 'warnings']
jwt = 1.4.2
cryptography = 1.5.2
Failed to get version of jwt module via pkg_resources: jwt
pkg_resources.require('cryptography')[0].version = 1.5.2
original = {'Hello': 'World'}
encoded = eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJIZWxsbyI6IldvcmxkIn0.ciaXCcO2gTqsQ4JUEKj5q4YX6vfHu33XY32g2MNIVEDXHNllpuqDCj-cCrlGPf6hGNifAJbNI9kBaAyuCIwyJQ
unencoded = {u'Hello': u'World'}
```

On **Environment B** the the encoding fails. You can see that I cannot tell what version of PyJWT is running. However this version of PyJWT doesn't have the algorithm `ES256` that I'm trying to use:

```
sys.version = 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016, 22:14:00) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]"
dir(jwt) = ['DecodeError', 'ExpiredSignature', 'Mapping', 'PKCS1_v1_5', 'SHA256', 'SHA384', 'SHA512', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'base64', 'base64url_decode', 'base64url_encode', 'binascii', 'constant_time_compare', 'datetime', 'decode', 'encode', 'hashlib', 'header', 'hmac', 'json', 'load', 'signing_methods', 'sys', 'timegm', 'unicode_literals', 'verify_methods', 'verify_signature']
dir(cryptography) = ['__about__', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__summary__', '__title__', '__uri__', '__version__', 'absolute_import', 'division', 'print_function', 'sys', 'warnings']
Failed to get version of jwt module using .__version: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
cryptography = 1.5.2
Failed to get version of jwt module via pkg_resources: jwt
pkg_resources.require('cryptography')[0].version = 1.5.2
original = {'Hello': 'World'}
encoding exception = Algorithm not supported
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PyJWT `.__version__` attribute appeared in `0.2.2` in [this](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/commit/d626f7e034c5a19627ba7a65dacc25d1e21d6573) commit.

Generally, to find the version of the package, that was installed via setuptools, you need to run following code:

```
import pkg_resources
print pkg_resources.require("jwt")[0].version
```

If `pip` was used to install the package, you could try from linux shell:

```
pip show jwt | grep Version
```

Same thing from inside the python:

```
import pip
print next(pip.commands.show.search_packages_info(['jwt']))['version']
```

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't work for me here? https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/ac3d0f2106b76e729cfb54008995181d

Comment: The reason for that is that the package was not installed via *setuptools*. This code lets you determine version only for that case.

Comment: Also included in the answer the command to find out version if `pip` was used.

Comment: Table, is there a way to show the version of jwt installed by `pip` from within my python code rather than from the Linux command line?

Comment: Yeah, you can try `pip` python-binding. `import pip;next(pip.commands.show.search_packages_info(['jwt']))['version']`. Also added in the answer

Comment: That's not answer the question, but it's good to know: to get the version of your library/application you can run `python setup.py --version` (with your virtualenv activated). This doesn’t work in your case because `jwt` is a dependancy…

Comment: Using the pip one and got the error message "module 'pip' has no attribute 'commands'".

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
print(jwt.__version__)
```

and that worked perfectly.